# What do Old Swedish "mz", "thz" mean?

Tags: swedish

What do Old Swedish "mz", "thz" mean?
I didn't find them in a dictionary.

[from](https://spraakbanken.gu.se/karp/#?mode=oldswedish&lang=eng&advanced=false&searchTab=special&hpp=25&extended=and%7CbaseformC%7Cequals%7Ck%C3%A4lo&page=1&resources=fsvm,soederwall,soederwall-supp,schlyter&search=lemgram%7C%7Cfsvm--%C3%B6sa..vb.1&map=false)

"ösa (-ir, -te. ösde MD 61 ), v. [Isl. asua] ösa. eg. och bildl. han fan först watn ij enom hwlum steen . . . ij sin hiälm monde **thz** ösa Al 4907 . hon . . . löpter ater til brunnin oc öser watn wllwallomen MB 1: 204 . al diwr vm kring fölghdo hanom. hwilkom han öste vatn af kälo til dryk KL 195 . j scullin ösa gudz nadha vatn . . . aff helarens nadha klädhom MP 1: 30 . paschasius . . . lät . . . ösa a hona wällande thiära ok oleum Bil 557 . öste julianus (sit blodh **mz** handom oc kastadhe höct) vp gen himnom ib 602 . hon . . . kom .. . til enna dywa källo, oc saa nidh i häne, enkte haffwande **thz** hon kwnne ösa **mz** Lg 220 . tha ösde thu af guddoms kello **mz** alle siäl MD 61 . - ösa, ösa ut, genom ösning tömma. öse thän thär wakin är (sentine latices excancles qui vigilzes) GO 891 . at hwar i sin stadh öse gruuona PfN 135 . huars snille ängin forma at gripa ey hällir än ösa (hauire) hauit Bir 2: 216 . ib 1: 171 . - ösa fram, framkast, uttala. ath menniskian . . . öser tolka mistankar fram Gers Frest 33 ."

Comment: @OmarL _Thz_ was fairly common in Mediaeval Scandinavia as an abbreviation for whatever the local form of ‘that’ was (_þæt_, _þadh_, _thet_, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for "mz", it's be an abbreviation for *mædh*, that makes sense.

*thz* is in all probability an abbreviation for the word means "that" in Old Swedish. According to Wiktionary, that's *þæt*, *dhet*.

Answer (score 2):

It is scribal abbreviation of the '-(e)t' lemme:
-(e)t = -z.
For more you can read this article: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tironian_notes